# Zend frame work multiple view from single action

Tags: zend-framework, view

Can anyone tell me how can i make more then one view through single action.

actually I have a controller action fetching data from model but I have to show data in 2 different views (half data in 1st  and rest in 2nd)

I know it is possible.

Can any one explain how it will be implemented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure whether you mean having two different views depending on a condition or two views at the same time.

From the action you can use:

```
$this->renderScript( 'views/page.phtml' );
```

and you can use multiple renderScripts and they will stack up and render in the order that they are called. Or you can have a condition separating them.

```
if($blah)
{
    $this->renderScript( 'views/page.phtml' );
    return;
}
else
{
    $this->renderScript( 'views/page.phtml' );
    return;
}
```

Is this the sort of thing you mean?

Answer (score 0):

Just use the render method of the controller action to display the view you want.

Refer to [Rendering Views](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.11/en/zend.controller.action.html#zend.controller.action.viewintegration.render) in the Zend reference manual for more information (you could also use [Named Segments](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.11/en/zend.controller.response.html#zend.controller.response.namedsegments) if needed/applicable).